# Facebook Connect oauth redirect URI URL for hybrid app on ionic framework / cordova

Tags: facebook, cordova, ionic-framework, phonegap-plugins

What do I need to enter for the OAuth redirect URIs on the facebook developer page when developing hybrid application with ionic framework / cordova?

[image: facebook oauth redirect url]

The current setup does not allow the app on the device to connect use facebook connect.

What should the URL look like?

Comment: How are you trying to connect to Facebook via the application?  Are you using the Facebook native plugin or ng-cordova-oauth?

Comment: Well I'm using the angular JS example from the facebook page https://developers.facebook.com/docs/javascript/howto/angularjs

Comment: @nicraboy also big thank you to you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I used https://github.com/nraboy/ng-cordova-oauth and added

- http://localhost/callback
- http://localhost:5000/oauthcallback.html

To Facebook dev page

Comment: Does localhost refer to 127.0.0.1 of the device in cordova? Or is it just local to cordova? Why I ask is i don't want someother app listening on localhost to hijak my oauth requests.